# Middleware not working for 2nd model i.e doctor but it works fine for admin.Here I am creating a two user model one is admin and one is doctor

Tags: node.js, passport.js, ejs, express-session

I am trying to build a two user login system one is admin and 2nd one is doctor. Here i am creating a middleware which is working fine for first one i.e admin but in case of doctor it is redirecting me again and again to the login page though my password and user name is correct.
please some one let me know how to create middleware for two model auth

```
    'use strict';
    var express = require("express"),
        app = express(),
        bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
        passport = require("passport"),
        LocalStrategy = require("passport-local"),
        mongoose = require('mongoose');


    var Admin = require("./models/admin");
    var Doctor = require("./models/doctor");


    var http = require('http');
    var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;


    //Set up default mongoose connection
    var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/seeddb';
    mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public", { redirect: false }));

    //PASSPORT CONFIGURTION
    app.use(require("express-session")({
        secret: "Rockey is the best",`enter code here`
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
    }));

    app.enable('trust proxy');

    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(require('flash')());
    //=========================================================

    //Admin Authentication
    passport.use('adminLocal', new LocalStrategy(Admin.authenticate()));
    passport.serializeUser(Admin.serializeUser());
    passport.deserializeUser(Admin.deserializeUser());

    //Doctor Authentication
    passport.use('doctorLocal', new LocalStrategy(Doctor.authenticate()));
    passport.serializeUser(Doctor.serializeUser());
    passport.deserializeUser(Doctor.deserializeUser());


    //=========================================================

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {    // to pass currentUser to each routes
        res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
        next();
    });

    //========================================================
    //Landing route
    //========================================================
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render("clinic/landing");
    });

    //=========================================================
    //Admin routes
    //=========================================================
    app.get('/admin-login', function (req, res) {
        res.render("admin/login");
    });

    //Sign Up
    app.post('/admin-signup', function (req, res) {
        var newAdmin = new Admin({ username: req.body.username });
        Admin.register(newAdmin, req.body.password, function (err, admin) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.redirect("/admin-login");
            }
            passport.authenticate("adminLocal")(req, res, function () { //local can be twitter fb for authentication
                console.log("Successfully signup Login to continue");
                res.redirect("/admin-login");
            });
        });
    });
    //Admin sign in
    // process the login form
    app.post('/admin-login', function (req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('adminLocal', { failureFlash: true }, function (err, admin, info) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            if (!admin) { return res.redirect('/admin-login'); }
            req.logIn(admin, function (err) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                return res.redirect('/admin/' + admin._id);
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });

    //Admin home
    app.get('/admin/:id', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        Admin.findById(req.params.id, function (err, admin) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                Doctor.find({}).exec(function (err, doctors) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    res.render("admin/adminhome", {"doctors" : doctors, admin: admin });
                });
            }
        });
    });

    //===============================================
    //Doctor routes
    //===============================================

    //Doctor login
    app.get('/doctor-login', function (req, res) {
        Admin.findById(req.params.id, function (err, admin) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.render("doctors/login");
            }
        });

    });


    app.post('/doctor-signup', function (req, res) {
        var newDoctor = new Doctor({
            username: req.body.username,
            fname: req.body.fname,
            lname: req.body.lname,
            email: req.body.email,
            exp: req.body.exp,
            dept: req.body.dept,
            address: req.body.address,
            hospInfo: req.body.hospInfo,
            desc: req.body.description,
        });

        Doctor.register(newDoctor, req.body.password, function (err, doctor) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.redirect("back");
            }
            passport.authenticate("doctorLocal")(req, res, function (){ //local can be twitter fb for authentication
                console.log("Doctor signup successfully Done");
                res.redirect("/doctor-login");
            });
        });
    });

    //Doctor sign in
    // process the login form
    app.post('/doctor-login', function (req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('doctorLocal', { failureFlash: true }, function (err, doctor, info) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            if (!doctor) { console.log("No doc found"); return res.redirect('/doctor-login'); }
            req.logIn(doctor, function (err) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                return res.redirect('/doctor/' + doctor._id);
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });

    //doctor home
    app.get('/doctor/:id', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        Doctor.findById(req.params.id, function (err, doctor) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.render("doctors/doctorhome", { doctor: doctor });
            }
        });
    });


    // //middleware to check whether it is logged in or not
    function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        }
        res.redirect("back");
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a code example that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Sorry as i am new to stack overflow i didn't know how to add code that time now i edited and added the sample code

Comment: Your comment flag has been declined. Please read about [how to flag comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373801/when-is-a-comment-hostile-or-unfriendly-educating-newer-users-how-to-flag-comm).